# Please I need help to define a function of two variables (t,x)!

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, education, language-design

Let's define the following function:

```
f[t_, x_] = t^2 + t*x*(1 - x)
```

such that $x \in (0,1)$ and `$t \in (0,0.02)$
The problem is when I want to define the following function:

```
z[t_,x_] = Interpolation[Table[{x, f[t, x] Piecewise[{{1, 0.2 < x < 0.8}}]}, {t, 0,0.02},{x, 0,1, 1/24}]];
```

This is not working!!
(I think the problem is because I discretize in space and not in time!!)

Comment: I'm not familiar with your goal but here are a couple of notes you probably missed: `_` for arguments in defining `f`, using `=` instead of `:=` in defining `z`, and also when you don't specify step in `Table` it's 1 which in your case `t` has almost no effect. Running `Table` alone will show you it will return a nested list not the kind of input `Interpolation` wants. Another thing is using similar names (`z` and `Table`). I think I should also remind using `ClearAll` before correcting the notes.

Comment: You have right, the problem is that I get a list not the kind of input Interpolation wants. and I don't know how to solve this problem, I need a way to define a function of two parameters, t and x such that ${t, 0, 0.02}$ and ${x, 0,1, 1/24}$!! I don't know how!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to sample your continuous function $f(t,x)$ at only discrete values of $x$, but be able to call it later for any value of $t$ then:

```
f[t_,x_]:= (t^2 + t x (1-x)) Piecewise[{{1,0.2<x<0.8}}];
```

which we can sample then using:

```
zdis[t_]:= Table[f[t,x],{x,0,1,1/24}];
```

You can plot all values then using:

```
Plot[Evaluate[zdis[t]],{t,0,0.04},PlotLabels-> Table[InputForm[x], {x, 0, 1, 1/24}]]
```

giving:

[image: Plots of zdis[t]]

Addendum:

To get the $i$th value where $x = i/24$ for $i\in [0,24]$ you can either just call

```
zdis[t][[i+1]]
```

or build this into the original definition as per:

```
zdis[t_,i_?IntegerQ]:= f[t,i/24];
```

where the `?IntegerQ` requires the input to be an integer.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for, I just need a little more detail please. after you define the table $zdis[t_]$, can you please show me how I can define a new function $g(t , i)$ such that for each value of $ t \in (0,0.02)$ and $i \in (0,1/24,1/12,....,1)$ I get the value !!

Comment: See the addendum to the answer. Note that the $i$ input in my answer is an integer, not a multiple of 1/24, which is harder to do (and unnecessay). Defining this secondary function ```zdis``` is not really necessary in the first place if you only ever call ```f[t,x]``` with values of $x \in [0,1/24,2/24,....]$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `FunctionInterpolation`is what you're looking for.

Try

```
f[t_, x_] = t^2 + t*x*(1 - x)
fip = FunctionInterpolation[f[t, x] Piecewise[{{1, 0.2 < x < 0.8}}], {t, 0, 0.02}, {x, 0, 1 }] 
Plot3D[fip[t, x], {t, 0, 0.02}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

For discrete interpolation in x we transform `f[t,x]` in a product `{t^2,t}. {1,x(1-x)`.

Now it's possible to interpolate x:

```
ip = Interpolation[Table[{x, Piecewise[{{1, 0.2 < x < 0.8}}] {1, x (1 - x)}}, {x, 0, 1,1/24}],InterpolationOrder->1];

Plot[ip[x],{x,0,1}]
```

[image]

Final function follows to `{t^2,t}.ip[x]`!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I see that you consider x in the whole interval (0,1). Me I need $(x, 0,1, 1/24)$.

Comment: That means you're looking for a discrete interpolation `,{x, 0,1, 1/24}`?

Comment: that's right, I'm looking to define a discrete function in space but not in time.!!

Comment: @walidfssm See my modified answer, now with discrete interpolation x.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But, this is not what I need. is it not possible to define it without separating it into a product!!